# How would you construct an aerial trolley transport system?

Tags: transportation, airships

I am researching alternative transport systems in a solarpunk setting. I am especially interested in systems where airships are pulled by the kinds of cables currently used in ski lifts and aerial ropeways.

Trolley boats and trolley buses are some of the most efficient transport systems invented. Could these technologies be combined and adapted to aerial use, so that a cableway pulled cargo attached to a neutral buoyancy or lighter-than-air vehicle. In some ways, this is a high-tech version of a horse-drawn canal barge. Horse-drawn canal barges can pull thirty times the cargo weight of land based carts. How much more could be pulled by cables when air resistance is the only drag factor? No on board engine or fuel is required, which reduces weight significantly, and the drag on water is a magnitude less than that created by road or rails. An aerial version would seem to offer many similar benefits.

I have seen a few patents from the 1890s describing vaguely similar ideas, but such a system is rarely found in fantasy and science fiction. This kind of transportation network was included in some of Jack Vance's early work, and then developed by Matthew Hughes in Black Brillon.

"The balloon-tram system had been a favorite project of the Archon Vanz, an imaginative and energetic innovator who had left several marks on the world. It was a mode of transporta­tion favored by those who had the leisure to arrive later than sooner and the desire to view the territories through which they passed from a different perspective.

The passengers rode in a capacious and well-appointed car that hung from the belly of a rigid-framed cylindrical airship. The lighter-than-air craft was tethered by a long cable to a dolly that was in turn slotted into a ground track that ran arrow-straight across flats and hills, crossing gorges and water obstacles on trestles and causeways.
An operator sat at a panel in the front of the car, adjusting the degree of
interaction be­tween the materials of which the track and dolly were made, which provided the energy to move the system."

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is a ropeway transportation system that pulls airships? How does it work, and what problems does it solve? I am sad to say that on a site with a very international audience, many people are most regretfully less than fully familiar with Canadian fiction.

Comment: The big problem with a towing tether is that it tends keeps the airship fairly close the ground, by far the most dangerous place for an airship to be. Unexpected errant breezes occur mostly near the ground, and can smash the airship into the ground, or vane it into the air. Airship operations in the early 20th century were based around spending as little time unsecured near the ground as possible.

Comment: The edited version still reads like an invitation to a discussion on the subject - it doesn't provide us a specific worldbuilding problem to be solved.

Comment: It is a good question but badly explained. Be more specific than "airships and cables". Describe what you are thinking about. What does the airship look like? What is at the other end of the cable? Is it a horse? Is it a bunch of horses maybe?

Comment: What does "the drag on water is a magnitude less than that created by road or rails." mean?

Comment: I have changed the question to something more focused. You want these hauled airships in your world. The question is why would they be used in your world and not the real one.

Comment: Thank you for all the editing advice.  As a newb here, all of your assistance is most appreciated.  I have rewritten the question entirely and hope it is a more acceptable.

Comment: @ Daron - According to this article, (https://www.jstor.org/stable/3104291) "The horse which moved 1 ton on land could pull 30 tons or more in a floating barge."

Comment: @ChristopherD.Winnan The edit is just background info. It does not make the question more focused. Your have not even said what is a trolley boat or trolley bus!

Comment: @ChristopherD.Winnan I have edited the first half for clarity. I suggest you remove the second half but keep whatever information is relevant to the question. Then ask a single focused question. You want a question where we can see when one answer is better than another. My last suggestion was "why would this develop?"

Comment: Why, please? Ski lifts and ropeways use those cables precisely because they're not "aerial" systems. They happen to move through the air, but not in any way mechanically different to you or I walking through air. 

If you really want airships pulled by cables, why not combine tram-lines with barrage balloons?

Comment: Why would you need something as overengineered and study as tramlines, for some that floats in the air and has neutral buoyancy.  Cables should be more than enough considering the reduction in overall drag.

Answer (score 1):

Let's identify what problem you're solving. You have airships that have the ability to stay off the ground, and can use propellers to go where they want. The ropeway would eliminate the need for propellers, but would lock you into specific paths.

Usually ropeways are only used when you need the rope to either guide something or to power something. Can you think of a situation when airships would need to be locked to a specific path? It would actually increase the crowding of the airships by limiting them to specific altitudes.

Can you think of a reason that the propellers would be inadequate for propulsion? Passing through an area of high wind might qualify.

Technologically, this is a solution looking for a problem. It doesn't exist in the real world, and not because we lack the tech to make it happen. What is different in your world that would require it to exist?

Comment: No engines and fuel (or people) on the airship means more cargo carried. Think more barges being towed by a tug than Zeppelins.

Comment: This points out a need for a process for keeping the zeppelin neutrally buoyant. As air pressure (or altitude) rises and falls, you need to change the temperature and/or pressure of the LTA gasses to keep the zeppelin from either crashing into the ground  or yanking your infrastructure off of it. You would need to manufacture tall poles, like with a ski lift, and clear trees around it to keep the mooring lines from getting tangled. I'm betting that you don't get much advantage over roads.

Comment: I'm thinking more an inverse rail system that pulls down on the balloon, yet has low rolling resistance. You just need to make sure it doesn't go to negative buoyancy, or too positive. Less contact force on the wheel/rail system relative to a train, so even less rolling friction.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you have "sky rails," basically ultra light-weight bridges (or even single rails) that can be raised over metropolitan areas, guiding and providing propulsion for lighter-than-air trains. Using linear induction (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1451049) you could get the zeppelins up to a significant speed.

Comment: How does it corner? It can't be physically steered by the rails like a normal train, putting propellers on it for steering would defeat the whole point of being tethered, a rudder seems like it wouldn't have enough authority at low speeds.

Comment: @Cadence, I was presuming that it wouldn't need steering because it was being pulled along.